# No Ubuntu Logo in splash screen while booting up

Tags: boot, graphics, intel-graphics

It seems this is a common problem. There are many questions regarding this problem even in this site, but all of them are related to Nvidia which is not useful for me.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 64bit on my Lenovo 500G with a switchable graphic card. I have disabled switchable graphic from Bios. So I am on my intel built-in GPU.

I don't know since when, but it is for a while I am not seeing Ubuntu Logo in splash Screen while booting up. In grub, splash is mentioned. While shutting down, I can see the Logo.

This is the output of `lshw`:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:25 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Any idea what is the problem and how I can solve it?

**>>> Please don't report as Duplicate to those questions which are related to Nvidia Graphic cards**

Comment: Does this negatively impact your computer? Or is it just an aesthetic issue?

Comment: I haven't noticed any performance impact. Perhaps just an aesthetic issue

Comment: If your computer is real fast you may just be blowing past it during boot.

Comment: I don't think I have a very fast system. It boots normally, like always. Taking around 50 second to boot. If you think it would be useful, I include dmesg in my question